# Should we protect identification questions that have been answered-accepted?

Tags: discussion

I have seen multiple times identification questions with an accepted answer being answered by a first poster.

Maybe they don't know how it works or they didn't see the correct answer, but for some reason they still answer (sometimes it could be spam)...

Is it a good practice to protect this kind of questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Questions should only be protected if the question is attracting low quality or duplicate answers from new users.  We should not use it to lock people from answering questions as that is completely against what SEs are suppose to do. If the answer is wrong it should be downvoted or ignored. There's no reason to completely block it.

This is only an issue do to the nature of identification questions which only pertains to the OP, but there can be many similar songs.

Comment: Hi Dom. Two examples came just after I asked this question, [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/5950/3260) and [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/5954/3260). I know that there can have similar songs, but when the OP has found what was looking for, I can't see the point of allowing low quality and duplicate answers... which are often the case when a new user answers an answered-accepted question.

Comment: @Bebs All answers to id questions right now are low quality as we don't enforce what answers should look like.    the additional answers on those questions are on par quality wise with the accepted answer and are all different songs. Let's fix the actual problem and not the symptoms.  We need to either standardize or limit these questions and answers.

Comment: OK, I'll write a question about this.

Comment: So it's ok to delete these answers, but not ok to protect the questions to prevent these answers to come?

Comment: @Bebs It seems what he's saying is that *if* it's okay to delete those answers, it's equally okay to delete the accepted answer as well. Either they are proper answers to the question or they're not.

Comment: @Bebs when an answer sits with a low quality flag for a month and nobody attempts to fix it and is just a link, yes.  Protecting _every_ answered id question  is ridiculous. Protection should only be when a question needs its not because no one should answer it anymore (an idea which doesn't exits on other SEs.). I've completely stopped trying to enforce quality on the questions because as a site no one else seems to care.