# When, if ever, are multiple answers appropriate for ID questions?

Tags: discussion

Clearly, when an ID question does not have an accepted answer, there can be multiple good-faith attempts to answer it. In a case, however, where an ID question does have an accepted answer (or one endorsed by the OP) is it ever acceptable to add additional answers if they also fit the criteria?  If so, what are the criteria?

See also: [What song has the phrase "waka waka wee"?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/what-song-has-the-phrase-waka-waka-wee/6694?noredirect=1#comment9377_6694)

[Should we protect identification questions that have been answered-accepted?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/should-we-protect-identification-questions-that-have-been-answered-accepted)

[How to Improve Quality](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/how-to-improve-quality/423#423)

Answer (score 1):

PRO: It's useful to people who have similar questions with different answers.    SciFi seems to encourage this, apparently successfully.  We already considered protecting ID questions with accepted answers and apparently decided against it.

Answer (score 1):

This comes back to if we care more about what the OP wants or more making the question open for others.

The problem is *wrong answers should be downvoted*. Nobody asking an ID question is looking for a song that fits X category, they are looking for one singular song. We as a site if we're saying other answers are "correct" via upvoting even it's not what the OP wanted is very disheartening and very much sends the wrong message especially since any question that has a positive score is considered answered.

We have to take care of questions asked on this site, not just upvote anything that is close enough to an answer. If we really want any song that fits a description be a valid good answer, then the questions asked need to be phrased in a way where that makes sense.  For example, the linked question is looking for one specif song that has the phrase "waka waka wee" that is the one the OP is thinking of. The question is not looking for *all* songs that have the phrase "waka waka wee".

If we really want ID questions to stay, we need to actually look out for the OP and make sure any answers actually answer their question.

Answer (score 0):

CON: It goes against the SE model of one definitive answer.  It probably means the original question is not exact enough.  It should be added as a comment instead, or edited into the accepted answer.

Comment: There can be more than one answer if the question if it tailored to that. ID questions have _one_ song to identify/find which is the problem.